# Aren't static variables limited to the compilation unit?

Tags: c

I have the following files:

`main.c`:

```
#include "ext.h"
#include "main2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  // printf("main - internal_static_variable: %d\n", internal_static_variable);
  // printf("main - internal_static_variable: %d\n", internal_static_variable);
  printf("main - external_variable: %d\n", external_variable);

  put_static_val(24);
  put_val(42);

  printf("main - internal_static_variable: %d\n", get_static_val());
  printf("main - internal_variable: %d\n", get_val());

  ++external_variable;
  print();
}
```

`main2.h`:

```
// main 2.h

#pragma once

void print();
```

`main2.c`:

```
// main2.c

#include "ext.h"
#include "main2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print() {
  printf("main2 - external_variable: %d\n", external_variable);
  printf("main2 - internal_static_variable: %d\n", get_static_val());
  printf("main2 - internal_variable: %d\n", get_val());
}
```

`ext.h`:

```
// ext.h

#pragma once

extern int external_variable;

void put_static_val(int v);
int get_static_val();
void put_val(int v);
int get_val();
```

`ext.c`:

```
// ext.c

#include "ext.h"

static int internal_static_variable = 0;
int internal_variable               = 1;
int external_variable               = 2;

void put_static_val(int v) {
  internal_static_variable = v;
}

int get_static_val() {
  return internal_static_variable;
}

void put_val(int v) {
  internal_variable = v;
}

int get_val() {
  return internal_variable;
}
```

When compiled and executed, the result is the following:

```
main - external_variable: 2
main - internal_static_variable: 24
main - internal_variable: 42
main2 - external_variable: 3
main2 - internal_static_variable: 24
main2 - internal_variable: 42
```

As expected, the variables not exposed in the header file (`internal_static_variable` and `internal_variable`) are not directly accessible.

What I don't get is the meaning of `static`. I know it limits the scope of a variable to the compilation unit, but isn't it enough *not* to declare a variable in the header file to hide it?

Also, I assumed that the static variable and the not-static variable would behave differently. Specifically, `internal_static_variable` would *not* be shared by the files including it (one instance for `main.c` and one for `main2.c`), but since I change its value from `main.c` and I get the changed valued in `main2.c`, there seems not to be any difference between the two.

Could you explain it, please? Thanks

Comment: Improve your code to not only print the value of variables but also their address, e.g. `printf("external_variable @%p: %d\n", (void*)&external_variable, external_variable);` and so on. Use also the debugger to run your program step by step.

Comment: `static` simply hides the symbol so the linker cannot see it.  That prevents another translation unit or library from accidentally using it.  Preventing accidents is a good thing, without namespace support it all turns into a big wad that is hard to unravel when it blows up.

Answer (score 4):

## Scope and Linkage

Identifiers have two properties that are relevant here: **scope** and **linkage**.

**Scope** is where an identifier is visible. You apparently already know that scope is limited to the file an identifier is declared in, and it may be further limited to a block or a function (or a function prototype) depending on where the identifier is declared and the keywords (such as `static` or `extern`) used when declaring it.

**Linkage** is a way of making different declarations of an identifier refer to the same object. There are three types of linkage: **external**, **internal**, and **none**.

If an identifier has **internal** linkage, it is not linked with identifiers in other translation units. An object called `foo` in one translation unit<sup>1</sup> cannot be accessed by name in another translation unit.<sup>2</sup>

If an identifier has **external** linkage, it can be accessed in another translation unit by declaring an identifier with the same name and also with external linkage. When the program is linked together, identifiers with external linkage are resolved by the linker so that they refer to the same storage.

## Problems With External Linkage

You can omit `static` and leave your identifiers with external linkage. As long as you are the only person writing your program, you can avoid problems. But this is not tidy; it leaves some things dangling, which can cause problems.

If you are writing routines to be used in other programs, leaving private identifiers with external linkage can be a problem, especially if they have simple, common names. A person who is using your routines in their own code might use the same name coincidentally, and then your two identifiers would be linked to the same object even though you need them to be different.

This can also occur intentionally. If you write a popular software package and leave private names with external linkage, some users of the package may explore what names are present and try to use them. This can result in people creating software which makes use of things in your software that were supposed to be private. Then you cannot develop new versions of the software that change the private parts without breaking existing software. That becomes a business problem. You may need to implement new algorithms inside the software package, but you do not want to break the existing source code of your customers. Declaring the names with `static` originally could avoid that.

## How Declarations Affect Linkage

When an identifier is declared with `static` at file scope, it has internal linkage. Beyond that, the rules for which linkage an identifier has are a bit complicated, due in part to history of how the C language developed:

- Declaring an identifier with `extern` gives it external linkage if no prior declaration is visible.
- If there is a visible prior declaration, `extern` leaves the identifier with the same linkage as in the previous declaration.
- A declaration of a function or an object at file scope without `extern` or `static` gives the identifier external linkage.
- A declaration of an object at block scope without `extern` has no linkage, even if `static` is used.
- Function parameters have no linkage.
- Identifiers of things that are not objects or functions (such as type definitions) have no linkage.

Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with internal linkage denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with **no linkage** denotes a unique entity. (This paragraph is a direct quote from C 2011 [N1570] 6.2.2, and the other information in this answer comes from there too.)

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> A translation unit is the combined source code resulting from all `#include` directives. I use the technical term “translation unit” rather than “source file” because an object called `foo` in one source file could be accessed in another source file by using the `#include` directive.

<sup>2</sup> An object with internal linkage can still be accessed in another translation unit by using a pointer, if you pass its address from one function to another.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a non-static global variable, it's still global. Even if it's not declared in a header file, it can still be declared in another [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So, what's the difference, in my example, between declaring the int variable static or not-static?

Comment: @pistacchio If it's not `static`, then some other *source*-file could do `extern int internal_static_variable;` and use it. If the variable is `static` then it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is extern (the default), the object file generated by this compilation unit will carry a named reference to its location. Whenever another object file is linked with the first and refers to the same named variable but does not provide its own definition, the linker will replace all instances of its use of that variable with its location. The CPU deals with memory locations during execution not variable names. This is why it being omitted in the header does not matter; later when you link the object files created from your .c source files, only then are global references resolved.

Static (outside of functions) is useful in that a single library/program can have multiple globally accessible variables under the same name. This prevents name collisions between modules which may both use a variable name for different purposes but make sense in their own contexts to use a variable name which just happens to be the same. As long as the variable is only needed in the current compilation unit, then you should make it static.

Comment: External is the default only at file scope, and only for identifiers of objects or functions. (Identifiers of typedef names, labels, and structure/union/enum tags are not external even if declared at file scope.)

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't get is the meaning of static. I know it limits the scope
>   of a variable to the compilation unit, but isn't it enough not to
>   declare a variable in the header file to hide it?

That would not prevent the variable being declared and therefore becoming accessible. It is the difference between security and obscurity.  By declaring it `static` it cannot be accessed externally *by name*, by simply not declaring it in a header you are only preventing access to those who do not know its name and data type.  A more likely scenario is that your object code or library is used elsewhere and you get an accidental name clash - such bugs are often difficult to fathom.

---

> I assumed that the static variable and the not-static variable would
>   behave differently. Specifically, `internal_static_variable` would
>   *not* be shared by the files including it (one instance for `main.c` and one for `main2.c`), but since I change its value from `main.c` and
>   I get the changed valued in `main2.c`, there seems not to be any
>   difference between the two.

Your code does *not* modify `internal_static_variable` in main.c; it modifies it *only* in ext.c.  ext.c happens to expose `internal_static_variable` through an accessor function, which in your example provides minimal protection, but as a single point of write access, provides a number of advantages over direct access to the variable, such as:

- It is possible to include code in the accessory to handle invalid input, by asserting, returning an error value, aborting, ignoring the value and *not* modifying the variable, or coercing to a valid value for example.  Such code might also be conditionally compiled so that it only performs checking in a debug build.
- The accessor function provides a single point in the code to place a debugger breakpoint to trap all write accesses.

Comment: Saying a variable cannot be accessed externally *ever* is not actually correct, especially when you emphasize *ever*. A true statement is that the object cannot be accessed by name. It can be accessed by address, if its address is passed to a function in another translation unit. This is important, for example, when diagnosing bugs and reasoning about whether an object might or might not have changed when an external function was called.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Good point.  However return a pointer to to data you had intended to hide would rather defeat the purpose.

Comment: Declaring an object to have internal linkage means you want to limit its name, not necessarily limit access by address. There are good reasons for passing pointers to local objects to other routines. Additionally, programs grow in size and complexity. It is not always easy to see whether the address of an object is passed to routines outside the current translation unit. It is easy, however, to edit this answer to be correct in this regard. A correct statement is that “An object declared static cannot be accessed by name in any other translation unit.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil : I agree that the statement was too emphatic (and have modified it).  Your point about there being "_good reasons for passing pointers to local objects..._" however is  a matter of opinion that I would have to disagree with - for the same reasons that global data is a poor design decision.  You have highlighted exactly the danger with such a practice in your next statement about programs growing in complexity.  The design practice point however is not directly relevant to the question and not perhaps a matter for further discussion I suggest.